# Flutter most effective way to retrieve data from firebase in a Tab Navigation

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to receive data for month week and day (day as default) from my firebase firestore.

[image]

The above image shows ma Tab Ui widget. Each of the tabs should give me data which I show users in a `FutureBuilder` with `ListView.Builder`.

I'm searching for a powerful way to display my data since week and month is not selected I dont have to load the content in the first step Also my request to firebase is always the same, only the date is changing. Im thankful for a nice and powerful solution.

Also Im not sure if this is the right approach, the data I'm requesting here is infinite in the future. How to work with that?

This is my request:

```
getData(DataNotifier dataNotifier) async {
    // demo data only

    List<Data> _dataList = [];
    DateTime _now = DateTime.now();
    DateTime _start = DateTime(_now.year, _now.month - 1, 1, 0, 0); // <- This will change

    QuerySnapshot snapshot = await db
        .collection('data')
        .where('dateWhenProofed', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: _start)
        .limit(30)
        .get()
        .catchError((error) => print("---- Failed: $error"));

    snapshot.docs.forEach((document) {
      Data data = Data.fromJson(document.data());
      _dataList.add(data);
    });

    dataNotifier.datalist = _dataList;
  }
```

And I want to display my data as List below the Tabs.
These are my tabs:

```
tabs: [
                                    Tab(
                                      child: Padding(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                            5, 0, 5, 0),
                                        child: Text(
                                          'Heute',
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              color: Colors.white,
                                              fontSize: 12,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Tab(
                                      child: Padding(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                            5, 0, 5, 0),
                                        child: Text(
                                          'Woche',
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              color: Colors.white,
                                              fontSize: 12,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Tab(
                                      child: Padding(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                            5, 0, 5, 0),
                                        child: Text(
                                          'Monat',
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              color: Colors.white,
                                              fontSize: 12,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                  controller: _tabController,
                                  isScrollable: true,
                                  indicatorWeight: 0.0,
                                  onTap: (){}, <---- we can do something here
                                )
```

,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's Timestamp field in Firebase and you can use it for calculating whether the data is in a given boundary.

you can add timestamp value to your data:

```
Timestamp.now()
```

for example,

```
 Timestamp get timeLimit {
    final limit = DateTime.now().subtract(const Duration(days: 1));
    return Timestamp.fromDate(limit);
  }
```

you can get the lower limit of timestamp value that is 1day from the moment when you query.

Then

```
QuerySnapshot snapshot = await db
        .collection('data')
        .where('timestamp', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: timeLimit)
        .limit(30)
```

Comment: This looks nice, thanks alot! As I said in my post the data I'm requesting will be infinite. Am I fine with this way of requesting it? And what should I do If user changes the tab to week for example? Im changing your function to the given date range, but what to do with the futurebuilder? Also do I have 3 FutureBuilders in total for each tab a single one with Listviews or just one futurebuilder changing the result? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean infinite? do you mean that there's no timestamp boundary? or amount of data is very large?

Comment: I mean the amount of data is very large. Sorry bout that. Im using one ListView.Builder now with FutureBuilder and if the user switches on a tab (day, week, month) im requesting the data by selected tab for the futurebuilder. With large amount of data now my question is this the common way?

Comment: If you are using tab controller you have to make 3 different list.view per each tabview and I think it is okay. if you must use only one list.view builder than you just make one list.view that receive inputs (e.g Stream) and any time you click button you can sink different inputs to the same stream controller.

Comment: I think it will be better to sort your data with timestamp and run query for monthly data once. In this way you can have cached monthly data and then filter it daily and weekly.

Comment: hyobbb thanks alot im learning really much from your answers. So if we request the query by month, how about the weekly and daily filtering, do I have to do this client side then? And: I thought using a Future instead of a Stream the main difference between them is that the Streams gives me data in realtime, and futurebuilder does give it to me per request. Wouldnt that be better for performance if i only call it if needed? I would only request this data if the user is opening the app

Comment: Yes. In that case you should filter them on client side. Also, you can use future without any problem.